# Using hash function for fast image duplication prevention

Tags: math, image-processing, hash

I develop website where people can upload images for using as textures.
I want to limit pressure on web-server by avoiding storing the same image twice.

As users can upload images very often I want to have a very fast technique to identify is uploaded image have a copy on web server and if it has when discard it and use already existing image.

Is it ok to use hash function for this task if I can accept possibility of different images having the same hash below 1e-5? What hash function is better suitable for my task?

Comment: Consider using blake2b since it's fast, wide spread, and collision resistant.  Alternatively, consider using SHA3 since it is almost as fast, almost as wide spread, and collision resistant.

Comment: Thank you! Can you roughly estimate collision probability for those hash functions?

Comment: They are cryptographic PRFs, so once you select your output size the probability is immediately apparent.

Comment: thanks again! you give me a bunch of confidence in my actions!